# Virtual Segregation of Data in Multi-tenant MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-schema, multi-tenant

This is more of a conceptual question so variations on the stack are welcome should they be capable of accomplishing the same concept.  We're currently on MySQL and expanding some services out into MongoDB.

The idea is that we would like to be able to manage a single physical database schema/structure so that adjustments, expansions etc. don't become overly cumbersome as the number of clients utilizing the structure grows into the thousands, tens of, hundreds of, etc. however we would like to segregate their data at this level rather than simply at the application layer to provide a more rigid separation.  Is it possible to create virtual bins for each client using the same structure, but have their data structurally separated from one another?

The normal way would obviously be adding Client Keys to every row of data either directly or via foreign relationships, but given that we can't foresee with 20/20 how hacks on our system might occur allowing "cross client" data retrieval, I wanted to go a little further to embed the separation at a virtually structural level.

I've also read another post here: [MySQL: how to do row-level security (like Oracle's Virtual Private Database)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527129/mysql-how-to-do-row-level-security-like-oracles-virtual-private-database) which uses "views" as a method but this seems to become more work the larger the list of clients.

Thanks!

---- EDIT ----

Based on some of the literature suggested below, here's a little more info on our intent:

The closest situation of the three outlined in the MSDN article provided by @Stennie would be a single database, multiple-schema, however the difference being, we're not interested in customizing client schemas after their creation, we would actually prefer they remain locked to the parent/master schema.

Ideally the solution would keep each schema linked to the parent table-set structure rather than simply duplicating it with the hope that any change to the parent or master schema would be cascaded across all client/tenant schemas.

Taking it a step further, in a cluster we could have a single master with the master schema, and each slave replicating from it but with a sharded set of tenants.  Changes to the master could then be filtered down through the cluster without interruption and would maintain consistency across all instances also allowing us to update the application layer faster knowing that all DB's are compatible with the updated schemas.

Hope that makes sense, I'm still a little fresh at this level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few common infrastructure approaches ranging from "share nothing" (aka `multi-instance`) to "share everything" (aka [`multi-tenant`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy)).

For example, a straightforward approach to your "virtual bins" would be to allocate a database per client using shared database servers.  This is somewhere in between the two sharing extremes, as your customers would be sharing database server infrastructure but keeping their data and schema separate.

A database-per-client approach would allow you to:

- manage authentication and access per client using the database's authentication & access controls
- support different database software (you mention using both MySQL which supports views, and MongoDB which does not)
- more easily backup and restore data per client
- avoid potential cross-client leakage at a database level
- avoid excessive table growth and related management issues for a single massive database

Some potential downsides would include:

- having more databases to manage
- in the case of a database where you want to enforce certain schema (i.e. MySQL) you will need to apply the schema changes across all your databases or support some form of versioning
- in the case of a database which preallocates storage (i.e. MongoDB) you may use more storage per client (particularly if your actual data size is small)
- you may run into limits on namespaces or open files
- you still have to worry about application and data security :)

If you do some research on multi-tenancy you will find some other solutions ranging from this example (isolated DB per client on shared database server architecture) through to more complex partitioned data schemes.

This Microsoft article includes a useful overview of approaches and considerations: [Multi-tenant SaaS database tenancy patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/saas-tenancy-app-design-patterns).

Comment: Thanks Stennie!  I've been assuming the only real world way to do this would be separate DB's on the same infrastructure like you point out... which we may only offer as a premium service depending on this line of thought. The obvious concern with this is maintaining consistency.

Do you know of other databases that offer the kind of thing I'm dreaming of... oracle...MS...Maria?  If its out there and there's development in this direction, I might consider waiting or even migrating if the cost/benefit is right.

Comment: BTW, that MSDN article is VERY helpful in illustrating different techniques using current features and the pros and cons, very much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you are after as far as consistency and other selection criteria (cost, features, support, .. ) but you can probably work out an approach with almost any database. In my experience the view support in Oracle and PostgreSQL is much more mature than MySQL, but I was an early adopter of MySQL 5 views which had some painful teething problems and are likely much better now. I wouldn't assume you *have* to use views, and in fact a per-database partitioning may be more performant/manageable.

Comment: I would be also be concerned about the potential disruption of schema alterations or repair for large databases, and look to keep databases to a reasonable size or use a NoSQL database. Aside from storage, other obvious considerations include the throughput of data you'll be reading/writing. There isn't a single best database choice for all uses so you really have to weigh up the criteria for your own application. A good approach might be to do a proof of concept with your candidate databases to get an idea of how difficult they are to manage for different scales and models of data.

Comment: I've updated the main question to clear up our intent a little based on the three approaches in the MSDN article, maybe this'll shed a little light on where I'm trying to go.

Comment: @oucil Unfortunately I don't think your edit makes the question any more specific to answer.  You probably need to do a bit more research first to be clearer on your requirements.  Schema surely isn't the only concern .. performance and storage requirements probably come into play.  You should also investigate [CAP Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) and the [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) pattern.  MVCC possibly fits your envisioned "eventually consistent" schema versioning approach better, but has other implementation caveats.

Comment: Was just hoping there was a quick solution, though it doesn't look like there's any established way of accomplishing this.  The easiest solution seems to be to keep all tenants in a shared schema and address performance through sharding and security though further work at the application layer.  It just lacks the physical separation of data I was hoping to achieve.  We may have to stick with added separation either via schema or DB as a premium service for the time being and deal with the added work of updating multiple instances.  Thanks for your help and references, all very helpful!

Comment: anyone has an update link to the MSDN article on multi-tenancy?

Comment: @ChrisF I updated the link to [Multi-tenant SaaS database tenancy patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/saas-tenancy-app-design-patterns).