# How Can I Make Fast Desktop Application With Remote Database?

Tags: java, mysql, performance, desktop-application, remote-server

I am going to make a desktop application with mysql database. My database tables are frequenlty changing -- almost 60% of the tables. So I think caching may be a bad idea. Can anyone suggest me:

How can I make a fast desktop application with a remote database ?

My language is Java.

Comment: There are two ways, from application perspective, threading will improve performance, from the database side, indexing will improve performance but I must say your question is too broad.

Comment: Unrelated note: If more than one user at a time access the database, consider a 3-tier architecture using e.g. Java EE, rather than accessing the database directly from the GUI.

Comment: Use fast enough hardware, apply load balancing, make sure you have no networking bottlenecks, make sure you have no disk I/O bottlenecks, make sure you know what you're doing, use a database storage engine and datamodel optimized for frequent changes, make sure the java runtime is configured to match your environment, make sure your OS is up to date, etc. The usual. The only true answer to this broad question is "make sure you do your job with proper thought, planning and design". When in doubt, hire expertise to support you.

Comment: Do not connect remotely to a database as you'd have to store the DB password in the program where everybody could find it (encryption is pointless when it runs on client machine). **So every user could access every piece of data** as there're [no row-based permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5527129/581205) and the workaround seems to add even more overhead.

Comment: What kind of data? The reason the answers don't contain much detail is that the question doesn't either. Perhaps messaging is better than querying but it's hard to tell without more info from you.

Comment: i am doing a voip billing system its like data of call history and balances and also users which have changes frequently .. i mean my voip server process millions of concurrent call so there will be sevaral insert and update . we have got a web version of the software but planned to have a desktop version .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem with most projects that have performance as their primary concern is that people tend make some exotic choices that end up complicating the project without any real benefits. Unless you have previous actual hands-on experience with the environment you will be working start simple.

- Set some realistic goals about how often you have to refresh your data *before* you start. If your data changes very frequently, eg. every second, does it make sense to try and show the changes in real time? A query every second will make everyone involved miserable.
- Use a thread to take care of the queries. You don't need more than one, since any more will only make the race conditions in the database worst.
- Design your database layer to be insulated from the rest of the application. Also time your DB-related operations from the beginning in order to track the impact of your optimizations.
- Start with Hibernate / ORMLite. Although I cannot talk about ORMLite, I have used (optimized) Hibernate in heavy load environments without any problems. If you have complicated objects you should give it a try, it sure beats using plain JDBC and implementing the cache mechanism yourself.
- Find out when you need lazy loading and when it's slowing you down (due to the select n+1 problem).
- If you have performance issues optimize. You don't have to map *every single* relationship. Use custom SQL in separate methods to get the objects you need when you need them. You can write a query that only returns table ids and afterwards ask Hibernate to load the corresponding objects.
- Optimize your SQL. Avoid joins, use subselects, where id in etc.
- Implement (database) paging if it makes sense.
- If all else fails, start using plain SQL. You' ll have already written the most complex queries and you'll know where your bigger bottlenecks are.
- You could use a local SQLite to save the less volatile data and talk to the database mainly to get lists of ids and the stuff that you're missing. For example if you have users and orders, you can assume that you will have many more new orders per minute/second than users per hour.

To sum up, set clear performance goals before you start, always use a separate thread for data retrieval, avoid reinventing the wheel and keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: i don't know if subselect are more faster then join as i used join in most cases ,, anyway this answer is look most sensible to me .. thanks

Comment: I was referring in cases where you can avoid joining multiple tables by using simple subselects and id IN (SELECT...) expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Here goes some generic approaches to the problem.

0) HW: make sure you are not having bottlenecks in you hardware, that you can cheaply increase. (adding HW is faster and cheaper that dev hours in most cases)

1) Caching:
Perhaps you can cache (locally or in a distributed cache like memcache) the 40% of data that tends to be immutable. You could invalidate the cache when data gets modified. You should choose the right entities and granularity level for building the keys.

2) Replication:
If the first is to much overhead, you could create slaves of your mysql and read from there. Again, you have to know when you can afford to have some stale data.

3) NoSQL:
Moving in that direction, but increasing the dev effort, you could move to some distributed store (take a look at the CAP theorem before making a choice)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your database structure and application. You can use an object relational mapping library like [ormlite](http://ormlite.com) and refresh objects loaded from database at the background with threads. With ormlite you may also use LazyForeignCollection to load only required data in your application.

Comment: my database is quite large and it is too difficult for me to use ORM cause there some big queries(we got our web version). I think from ORM it is difficult to generate complicated and big queries .. what i thought earlier is making a extra thread which will be fetch data and cache it or put into some local database like sqlite .. but i don't know its a good idea or is there any better idea

Comment: You can run any query with ormlite, you can directly run raw queries.

Comment: @Fisherman Copying your data on a local DB would result in the same issues than caching your data

Comment: @C.Champagne a another thread will run behind the scene.Which will be synchronize the remote db to local. but because of frequently changes data on remote db. May be calling all the time for synchornizing is a bad idea , Or Need a idea to change just the changes. cause Now We are not keep tracking on query that changes i mean i am planning to write all the changes in SQL format and the thread will run on local database is that a good ideaa  .. well i don't know cause i am not that experienced

Answer (score 0):

Minimize unnecessary database call.

If your fields on database is changing, you can shift from relational to NoSQL database like MongoDB.

You can perform multithreading on the server side for data processing and clustering of application servers. While using multithreading use it effectively, be aware of the `sychronized` keyword, it will degrade the performance to some extend.

Perform best practice of coding, don't use more instance variable, try to use local variable, it will make you thread safe also.

You can use Mybatis for ORM also for large queries.

You can perform caching on DAO layer, service layer and even in client side but be sure to sychronize with the database, you can use different caching soutions.

You can do database indexing for first retrival.

Do not use same service for large data querying break it down into different services which will help u to process in multithreading way.

If the application is not very hard real time system you can use messaging solution also, like asychronously processing of data.