# How to prevent access to sensitive data in an app that's used internally in a company?

Tags: database, security

My company has started building an app that's going to be used heavily internally and also by other companies. It will contain sensitive data that we'd like to limit access to. Our developers are the main concern as they can bypass any permissions and connect directly to the database.

The data belongs to a user but can also be shared with others, so it needs to be available to either one or more users, but not all.

What can we do? Encryption comes to mind, but afaik that would only work if the data was accessible only by one user, otherwise how could I share the encryption key?

The only other solution that comes to mind is to host a separate instance for internal use where only one person (e.g. CTO) has access to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you shouldn't allow direct DB access from this application, but instead have a custom service where the app will authenticate with the current user's credentials and only then that custom service will allow access to the data according to ACL. That's actually quite complex way of doing this, although probably the most robust.

Another option is to have different users for the database and use views as described here - [MySQL: how to do row-level security (like Oracle's Virtual Private Database)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527129/mysql-how-to-do-row-level-security-like-oracles-virtual-private-database)